# Why can't get the right value of dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have following codes in asp.net:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlApp" runat="server" />
<asp:button id="btnSmt" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

and code behind:

```
    private void btnSmt_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
            lbl.Text = ddlApp.SelectedItem.Value;           
    }
```

The logic is very simple. Get the selected value of dropdownlist and pass it to lbl.text.

But the problem is no matter how I try, the text show the fist value of list in the dropdownlist rather than the selected value.

And I notice that everytime I click the button the page refresh.

Please help.

BTW, I have the following event binding:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {    
            this.btnSmt.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSmt_Click);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
            this.ddlApp.SelectedIndexChanged +=new System.EventHandler(this.ddlApp_Change);

        }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to do the binding for the dropdownlist in

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

Else it will re-build the items for the dropdown list on every postback and
therefore only return the currently selected item in the new collection - which is the first.

It also looks like you're missing the `btnSmt_Click` on the button - but you've probably set it somewhere else...

Comment: How to do the biding in if(!Page.IsPostBack)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx under 'examples'. Insert your ddlApp.DataBind(); (Or whatever you're doing) there...

Answer (score 0):

First of did you debug this??? Cause the C# code seems corrent.

Try changing this:

```
<asp:button id="btnSmt" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

To

```
<asp:button id="btnSmt" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSmt_Click" />
```

if this truely is your code your click event would never have been caught, therefor if you would put a breakpoint in your C# code you would have seen that the action is not triggered.

Anyway, hope it helps